# Oracle Forms 10g - why do I have to click save so that my insert query will save to database

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

why do i have to click save button in the upperleft on formservlet so that my insert query will save to database? im sorry guys, quite newbie here thanks

[image]
here is my pl sql code in add button trigger:

```
begin
insert into tb_distributor
      (distributor_id, distributor_name, distributor_type, distributor_desc)     
 values
      (distributor_id.nextval,:DISTRIBUTOR_NAME, :DISTRIBUTOR_TYPE, :DISTRIBUTOR_DESC);
commit;

end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Oracle Forms provides a great deal of functionality for you so that you don't have to write it. For example, if you base a block on a table, and if the user enters data and clicks "Save", Oracle Forms knows whether to execute Insert, Update or Delete statements appropriately followed by a Commit.

In your case, you have ignored that functionality and have hardcoded an Insert and Commit in your button code. Therefore, the user *does not have* to click the Save button, because the data has already been "saved" by your Add button.

Answer (score 0):

open the property palette for this data block and change the database data block item to `NO`
and start writing your PL/SQL manually.